# FirewallD blocks inbound connections to Docker containers OpenSUSE Leap 15.3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, opensuse

I've got Nginx and a few other containers running under `docker-compose`.
I can access the web server from the host machine, but not from a remote one under port `80` and `443`. Once I disable `firewalld`, I can access the Docker container, signifying this is a firewall issue. I've tried every single possible solution that people used for CentOS and Fedora, but they didn't work for me. Plus, I'm using Docker 20, so this shouldn't be a problem for me as there is a `docker` zone in `firewalld` that's supposed to configure everything.

My active zones:

```
docker
  interfaces: docker0 br-5da83ae671bb br-7918f1f94df9
public
  interfaces: br0 eth0
trusted
  interfaces: tun0
  sources: 10.0.0.0/24
```

The network I'm running the containers on is `br-7918f1f94df9` which has ipv4 `172.18.0.1/16`

In general, does anyone have any commands for me to try to see if it gets fixed? Let me know if I need to include anything else.

Epilogue: Maybe I'm just pissed because I've been having this issue for the past two days now, but I think that SUSE is just a terrible distro for user-friendliness because I keep getting issues like this that seemingly have no fix. What's a better distribution in your opinion?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the interface docker0 from being managed by firewalld

Check the docker documentation [https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#integration-with-firewalld)

Please substitute the appropriate zone and docker interface

```
 firewall-cmd --zone=docker --remove-interface=docker0 --permanent
 firewall-cmd --reload
```